# Q: Power BI for Azure Log Analytics / Monitor in Multi-Tenancy Scenario

Tags: powerbi, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor-workbooks

**Background**: Used Azure Workbook to create dashboard visualization for multi-tenancy scenarios. However, the visualization part is not that robust in Azure Workbook. So thinking of using Power BI.

**Questions**:
I just wanted to check with all the Azure Log Analytics practitioner here in regards to how they implement/ integrate Power BI with Azure Log Analytics in a multi-tenancy scenario?

What I know so far about PowerBI Integration with Azure Log Analytics:

- At the moment it only support Exporting log search query into PowerBI using "Blank Query".
- No native integration/ connection between the two

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I thin you can use the Azure Data Explorer connector to query from Log Analytics since they are both effectively Kusto databases

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/power-bi-connector

Comment: Thanks Martin, let me try if this could work.